# Issue on sending email from C# code throw smtp

Tags: c#, email, smtp

This is not duplicate question . I have already read so many question and tried almost all answers . 
I am getting timeout error on client.Send(mail);

```
 public void sentEmail()
    {
        MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("MyEmailAddress");
        MailAddress toAddress = new MailAddress("nikunj.jani@outlook.com");

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(fromAddress.Address, toAddress.Address);
        mail.Subject = "Testing";
        mail.Body = "contents.";

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Host = "mail.webin.pt";
        client.Port = 465;
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Timeout = 10000;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("MyEmailAddress", "myPassword");

        try
        {
            client.Send(mail);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Try  increasing the time out

Comment: @preciousbetine I also tried with more time out

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to ping the server and check if any connection is possible.
2. Try sending the same Mail from a Desktop Client.

(Those might help finding serverside errors)

3. Try with a increased timeout

Comment: It is working from thunderbird . this given screen shoot is thunderbird's configuration